# How to Creating dynamic Menu from JSON using AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

Here's the Plunk Code can Verify Now also

http://next.plnkr.co/edit/vrI2haNy1zYPDcCWh7gj?p=preview&utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=worker&utm_campaign=next&preview

Java Script Code: it is containing dummy json there root node is Admin System and there sub menu are Like Angular, Linux, Server

Here UI will be shown as Given Below Format and this Menu will be able to Expendable and Close able or collapse so this will be fetch the data as from Service and same way can be use in project

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller("MainController", ["$scope", 
        function($scope){
          $scope.bodyText = "Test Menu";


           $scope.showSubmenu = function(item) {
            if($scope.activeParentIndex === item){
                $scope.activeParentIndex = "";
            }else{
                $scope.activeParentIndex = item;
            }
        }

        $scope.isShowing = function(index) {
            if($scope.activeParentIndex === index){
                return true;  
            } else{
                return false;
            }
        };

        $scope.modulos = 
          [{"module":"Admin System ",
           "adm_modulo_id":1,
           "submodule":[{"res":"Angular","url":"#/admin/1"},
                        {"res":"Linux","url":"#/admin/2"},
                        {"res":"Server","url":"#/admin/3"}
                        ]

          }];

        }]);
```

Html Code: it will show dummy json code as menu and sub-menu

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.x" data-semver="3.0.3" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.9"></script>
  <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.10.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    {{bodyText}}

    <ul class="sidebar-menu" ng-repeat="m in modulos">
      <li class="treeview" ng-repeat="(itemIndex, item) in modulos">
        <a ng-click="showSubmenu(itemIndex)">
          <i class="fa fa-table"></i> <span>{{item.module}}</span>
        </a>

        <ul class="sub-nav" ng-show="isShowing(itemIndex)">
          <li ng-repeat="sub_element in m.submodule">
            <a href="{{sub_element.url}}">{{sub_element.res}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: And what is question? Plunker is working.